# Starting a CockroachDB server cluster on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cockroachdb

I want to run CockroachDB on my Mac for local development purposes, but am not sure how to get everything up and running...installing the database, connecting it to my app, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Install CockroachDB on Mac OS X](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/install-cockroachdb.html) and then run `cockroach start --background`.

With Cockroach running, you’ll need to [create a database](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/create-database.html) and [tables](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/create-table.html), etc.

From there, you can connect your application to CockroachDB using the postgres wire protocol, connecting to localhost (or equivalent) on port 26257. You can find more information about those connections [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/build-an-app-with-cockroachdb.html)

Comment: Probably easier to use Docker https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/start-a-local-cluster-in-docker-mac.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah docker is a lot better to use to quickly up and run the CRDB